# C - program compiling, but unable to provide arguments

Tags: c, shell

I'm on a Mac and in terminal I'm compiling my program

```
    gcc -Wall -g -o example example.c
```

it compiles (there are no errors), but when I try to provide command line arguments

```
   example 5 hello how are you
```

terminal responds with "-bash: example: command not found"

how am supposed to provide the arguments I want to provide after compiling?

Comment: You're not running the program. Your shell is looking for a command on its `$PATH` called `example`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: `Run code run.  C code run.` -- Anonymous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a compilation issue, but an issue with your shell. The current directory is not in your `PATH` (look with  `echo $PATH` and use `which` to find out how the shell uses it for some particular program, e.g. `which gcc`).

I suggest testing your program with an explicit file path for the program like

```
./example 5 hello how are you
```

You could perhaps edit your `~/.bashrc` to add `.` at the end of your `PATH`. There are pro and conses (in particular some possible security issues if your current directory happens to be sometimes a "malicious" one like perhaps `/tmp` might be : bad guys might put there a `gcc` which is a symlink to `/bin/rm` so you need to add `.` at the end of your `PATH` if you do).

Don't forget to learn how to use a debugger (like `gdb`). This skill is essential when coding in C (or in C++). Perhaps consider also upgrading your `gcc`  (Apple don"t like much its current GPLv3 license so don't distribute the recent one; try just  `gcc -v` and notice that the latest [released GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) is today 4.8.1).

Answer (score 5):

Run it like this with path:

```
   ./example 5 hello how are you
```

Unless the directory where the `example` binary is part of the PATH variable, what you have won't work even if the binary you are running is in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

`./example 5 Hello how are you` is the syntax you're looking for.

[This article](http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html) lends a good explanation as to why this is important.

Basically, when you hit `Enter`, the shell checks to see if the first set of characters is an absolute path. If it's not, it checks the `PATH` variable to find executables with the name of the command you are trying to run. If it's found, it will be run, but otherwise it will crash and burn and you will become very sad.